# CSS overflow scrolling and hidden scrollbar (iOS)

Tags: ios, css, scrollbar

In my app, I need to use

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Because **the scroll on iOS feels too "hard". But I need to hide the scrollbar.**

I have something like this:

```
.container {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar  {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

Now the scroll feels very fluid, but I can still see the scroll bar...

Comment: The "Hacking with a parent" example here works in Safari on iOS 12.2 in the XCode simulator: https://output.jsbin.com/lohiga

Comment: My understanding is that they add some extra bottom padding so the horisontal scrollbar is pushed down. Then they stick it inside a wrapper element with a fixed height and `overflow-y: hidden` so that the scrollbar stays inside that hidden overflow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of May 2020, this was the only solution that allowed me to hide the horizontal scrollbar on iOS Safari - including when the website is installed on the home screen as a PWA.

The idea is to make your container slightly higher than it needs to be with a `padding-bottom`, and to clip out that extra space where to scrollbar appears with `clip-path`.

Here is a snippet:

```css
.scroll-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 30px 0);
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

This does have the disadvantage of adding extra space, which does push down the other elements below. This issue could be negated / prevented with a negative margin. It wouldn't be super clean, but it would work.

Ex.:

```
.scroll-container { margin-bottom: -30px; }
```

Comment: Agreed, unfortunately this is the only method that works on iOS. Some of the above methods work on desktop but not iOS as the OP mentioned

Comment: This is the right answer, everything else is not working.

Answer (score 16):

As seen here: https://forum.webflow.com/t/how-do-i-hide-the-browser-scrollbar-from-appearing-when-a-user-scrolls/59643/5

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none; // Safari and Chrome
}
```

seems to work.

Answer (score 6):

I just played with [this](https://codepen.io/devstreak/pen/dMYgeO) CodePen and it seems that if you set the `background-color` to `transparent` for all three properties below (and in this example also remove `box-shadow`s), the scrollbar is not visible at all:

```css
#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  //    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  background-color: transparent;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  //    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

This was tested in Chrome Desktop, Chrome for Android, and iOS Safari (v8.4) on an iPhone 6+.

I would however recommend for user experience (usability/accessibility) to keep the scrollbar visible though, as even I, knowing what I was doing, got a bit confused when there was no scrollbar.

Comment: what ios version?

Comment: The CodePen no longer works on iPadOS as of today

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, this works:

```
.container ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

It's probably a good idea to scope it to the parent container of the scrollbar you want to hide and not use it globally.

Answer (score 3):

Just styling normal CSS and I don't know why it's working perfect...

```
.list {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.list .item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing (2019) I think the only way to handle this to use overflow to hide the scrollbar.

```css
/* box-sizing reset */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* 
   scroll container with overflow
   set to hidden
*/

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 20vh;
  outline: 1px solid;
}


/*
   scroller overflowing the container by 2rem
   and a 2rem bottom padding to make content 
   match the container height
*/

.scroller {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100% + 2rem);
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}


/*
  slides
*/

.slide {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* just a bit of color */

.a {
  background: orangered;
}

.b {
  background: gold;
}

.c {
  background: olive;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="slide a">A</div>
    <div class="slide b">B</div>
    <div class="slide c">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```